# How to open files (read-write permissions) of my Android device using Ubuntu 16 directly?

Tags: usb, permissions, android

Always, when I plug in my Android device using MTP connectivity to my pc and try to open an mp3, pdf, or whatever kind of this file I end up with an error message that states, it could not read that file. However, if I copied that file to my computer and open it from the hard disk, it will open up (play, read the pdf,..etc.). What so far I have understood is my Ubuntu 16 doesn't have the permission to access-read-write the files within my Android storage. And when I check the permissions of both the internal storage and the SD card, it shows "the permission could not be determined". For example, when I open an mp3 file using VLC player, a message pops-up with "VLC could not read the file (Input/output error)."
I looked around many solutions on the web without success,

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot use Ubuntu to bypass Android rules or permissions via MTP.

MTP is a way for the Android device to *pretend* to look like a storage device instead of another computer. But the Android system is still active and in control of it's own storage.

Android processes each request itself before passing the result to Ubuntu. And, of course, Android won't violate it's own rules and permissions.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, in Windows 7 I can do that sort of thing. no?